# std::out_of_range at memory location error at getline

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ifstream, getline

I'm very new to c++ there is a good bit of code here, so im going to do my best to condense it to the problem area. when I try to get user input using getline im getting this error. Since i don't expect spaces in the file names(i made the files)i use cin << which worked fine, but then got the same error when trying to read the file. the code is as follows

```
// includes here

using namespace std;

//other prototypes here
string getUserDataFromFile(vector<int>&, int&, string);


int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    numbers.reserve(50);
    int numberOfElements = 0;
    int number = 0;
    int numToFind = 0;
    int numberPosition = -1;
    int useFile = 0;
    string filename = "";
    string fileReadMessage = "";
    string output = "";
    string outFilename = "";


    cout << "Would you like to load the data from a file?(1 for yes 0 for no)";
    cin >> useFile;
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
    //get user data for manual input
    if(useFile == 0)
    {
        //code here for manual input(works fine)...
    }
    //get userdata for file input
    else
    {
        cout << "Please Enter the file path to be opened" << endl;

        //fixed after adding cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'); 
        //see next function for another problem
        getline(cin, filename);

        fileReadMessage = getUserDataFromFile(numbers, numToFind, filename);
    }

    //some code to get data for output


    return 0;
}




//function to get user data from file
//@param v(vector<int>&) - vector of integers.
//@param numToFind(int&) - the number we are looking for
//@param filename(string) - the filename of the file with data
//@return message(string) - a message containing errors or success.
string getUserDataFromFile(vector<int>& v, int& numToFind, string filename)
{
    string message = "File Accepted";
    string line = "";
    int numOfElements = 0;
    int count = 0;

    ifstream fileToRead(filename.c_str());

    //using 'cin >>' in main, the program runs till here then breaks

    //if message is a file, extract message from file
    if (fileToRead.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(fileToRead,line))
        {
            //code to do stuff with file contents here
        }
        fileToRead.close();
    }
    else
    {
        message = "Unable to open file.";
    }
    return message;
}
```

I left a couple of comments in the trouble areas and left out most of the code that i haven't had trouble with or haven't been able to test. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

So my first issue was fixed by the addition of cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'); any guesses on the next problem? its the line if (fileToRead.is_open()) in the next function

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
cin.ignore();
```

before:

```
getline(cin, filename);
```

Otherwise, ENTER you typed after entering `useFile` will be read into `filename`.

Comment: Better is `cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');` which ignores all pending input on the same line. Your version ignores a single character which might not be enough.

Comment: Thanks very much! Any clue on the second problem?